# Photoshop & Gimp simpler alternatives

Tags: photoshop

While doing web development, I often need to edit images. Not photos, not creative work, just simple editing. For example: adding shadow on a button, resizing multiple images, tweaking few pixels here and there, etc.

Photoshop always felt like a huge overkill (not to mention the price). Gimp's price tag is right, but it's still an overkill and somehow I feel clumsy while using it.

So what free/ open source Windows products are simpler yet do the same job?

Note that if product was really great, I would consider paying up to $50 but no more than that.

Comment: i use paint.net with Alpha mask plugin.

Comment: How does this relate to programming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PAINT.NET
This may be an option. I know that I have used this in the past but it may not be exactly what you need. There are plugins for it though I believe.
http://www.getpaint.net/

Answer (score 1):

you can use Paint.Net on http://www.getpaint.net/download.html

Its free